# Modify Balanced Random Forest Sampling

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, imblearn

I want to change the sampling type in the BalancedRandomForest library from [RandomUnderSampling](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html) to [ClusterCentroid](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids.html), I have changed this part

```
self.base_sampler_ = RandomUnderSampler(
        sampling_strategy=self._sampling_strategy,
        replacement=self.replacement,
    )
```

become this

```
 self.base_sampler_ = ClusterCentroids(
        sampling_strategy=self._sampling_strategy,
        replacement=self.replacement,
    )
```

That code i modified is in line [#386](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/4162d2d8ef127a81238ee72ebabac55642daee7c/imblearn/ensemble/_forest.py).

after I run on jupyter notebook, I got an error like this

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-098f56165cd0> in <module>
      2 
      3 classifier = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=5)
----> 4 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    481 
    482         # Check parameters
--> 483         self._validate_estimator()
    484 
    485         if not self.bootstrap and self.oob_score:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_estimator(self, default)
    371         self.base_sampler_ = ClusterCentroids(
    372             sampling_strategy=self._sampling_strategy,
--> 373             replacement=self.replacement,
    374         )
    375 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    638                           FutureWarning)
    639         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
--> 640         return f(**kwargs)
    641     return inner_f

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replacement'`
```

I don't know what to do now, is it still possible to change RandomSampling to ClusterCentroid ? Thanks.